# MySQL Replication ERROR 1130: error conecting to master

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm having difficulty connecting MySQL slave database to master using MyWorkBench.

I tried:

1. executing

   ```
   CREATE USER 'replication'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'replication'@localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   ```
2. using IP address instead of the server name

I confirmed that:

- I followed all the steps for setting server_id for slave and master
- I could ping both master and slave servers

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

- Check the quotes.
- `ON *.*`

  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'replication'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;